# How fix missing headers error and validation of response headers?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, http-headers

I am creating React and Laravel website and below issue was shown in the console.

[image: issue]

cors.php

```
<?php

return [


    'paths' => ['api/*','login','register','admin/*','sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],

    'allowed_origin' => ['http://localhost:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => [  
        
        'Content-Type', 
        'Authorization', 
        'Accept',
        'Accept-Language',
        'Content-Language',
        'Origin',
        'X-Requested-With',
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        
        //'X-CSRF-TOKEN',
        'Access-Control-Request-Methods',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers'
        
        ],

    'exposed_headers' => [
       // 'Access-Token',
       // 'Uid',
        'Authorization', 
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
        
    ],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

What is the issue of my cors.php and what are valid and invalid headers which I put?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Issue with React app and Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158474/cors-issue-with-react-app-and-laravel-api)

Answer (score -1):

have you confirmed the frontend origin is "http://localhost:3000" as you allowed in cors.php only this

Comment: Yes I confirmed @Shawinder

Answer (score -1):

add
allowed-origin to * in your code.

Comment: I tried this. It did not work @Anand