# Next.js register request blocked by CORS policy

Tags: laravel, next.js, cors, fetch

I'm making a simple frontend with next.js, and making a register request to a local API with fetch, but I keep getting this error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/register' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How do I resolve this? I'm using Laravel 10.

I tried adding `composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors` but that also returns a lot of errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Issue with React app and Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158474/cors-issue-with-react-app-and-laravel-api)